# Accessing MIB objects

Tags: python, linux, snmp

I want to develop a python code that will run on a remote Linux server and which can use all the functionalities of SNMP like SNMPGet, SNMPSet, SNMPWalk. Basically I want to create Expression MIBs that will be helpful in probing. I do not understand how to start with it. Can anyone please help me out with how do I create Expression MIBs and access them from the Python script.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using pysnmp for SNMP request/response, it works fine. you can reference it here http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How do Expression MIBs work exactly?
Can you provide me a sample code of how it looks so that I can practice more on that?

Comment: you can reference it here. Usually, you need to define the MIB first, then use pysnmp to parse it . https://github.com/mjulian/pysnmp-examples/blob/master/poll.py